# Swift Project Terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, nsexception

> Unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7feca9469620 2016-05-10
>   19:34:58.781 TribeA2[76123:4834825] *** Terminating app due to
>   uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[TribeA2.RegisterPageViewController registerButtonTapped:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7feca9469620'

Terminating with uncaught exception of type `NSException`.

```
import UIKit

class RegisterPageViewController: UIViewController {



@IBOutlet weak var userFirstNameTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var userLastNameTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var userEmailTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var userPasswordTextField: UITextField!


var databasePath = NSString()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let filemgr = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    let dirPaths =
        NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory,
                                            .UserDomainMask, true)

    let docsDir = dirPaths[0]

    databasePath = (docsDir as NSString).stringByAppendingPathComponent(
        "users.db")

    if !filemgr.fileExistsAtPath(databasePath as String) {

        let userDB = PersonDatabase(path: databasePath as String)

        if userDB == nil {
            print("Error: \(userDB.lastErrorMessage())")
        }

        if userDB.open() {
            let sql_stmt = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS USERS (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, FNAME TEXT, LNAME TEXT, EMAIL TEXT, PASSWORD TEXT)"
            if !userDB.executeStatements(sql_stmt) {
                print("Error: \(userDB.lastErrorMessage())")
            }
            userDB.close()
        } else {
            print("Error: \(userDB.lastErrorMessage())")
        }
    }


}


@IBAction func saveData(sender: AnyObject) {
    let userDB = PersonDatabase(path: databasePath as String)

    if userDB.open() {

        func displayMyAlertMessage(userMessage:String)
        {
            let myAlert = UIAlertController(title:"Alert", message:
                userMessage, preferredStyle:
                UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);

            let okAction = UIAlertAction(title:"Ok", style:
                UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler:nil)

            myAlert.addAction(okAction)

            self.presentViewController(myAlert, animated:true,
                                       completion:nil)

        }


        let insertSQL = "INSERT INTO USERS (fname, lname, email, password) VALUES ('\(userFirstNameTextField.text)', '\(userLastNameTextField.text)' '\(userEmailTextField.text)', '\(userPasswordTextField.text)')"

        let result = userDB.executeUpdate(insertSQL, withArgumentsInArray: nil)

        if !result {
            displayMyAlertMessage("All fields are required")
            print("Error: \(userDB.lastErrorMessage())")
            return
        } else {
           displayMyAlertMessage("Thank you for registering \(userFirstNameTextField.text)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in `RegisterPageViewController` you were created the  `registerButtonTapped` button action, but button  method not implemented, if you are not used the `registerButtonTapped`  delete from attribute inspector, else implenent the button action on class like the following

```
func registerButtonTapped(sender: UIButton)
    {
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

In the interface builder if you right-click on that button, a popup will be shown where you can see that you have "action" connected with name `-registerButtonTapped:` to your class, but actually you haven't implemented that method (or you deleted it for some reason). So you must delete that connection by clicking on x button in that popup either implement `-registerButtonTapped:` method.

Answer (score 0):

If you right click the button,the button will show the action or variables which are associated.please check that if it is available in your controller